# CSS Problem. @font-face issue with text

Tags: html, fonts, css, font-face

*ANSWERED!!!***

http://www.urbanelementz.ca/

Please view that URL. You can see the sample text I have written in the 2nd text box. I'm trying to control it using @font-face using css and it's not working correctly. Please view the @font-face code in the css file and the .column2 code in the css file.

Can someone see why it's not working properly? It seems to go to the default font.

Comment: If this question has been answered, please give credit to the person who answered it by clicking the GREEN CHECK by the answer that solved it. Gives them credit for the work they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your font is returning a 404 Not Found. Check your URL.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks so much Thomas! Simple fix. I had my fonts folder in the local directory. Should have been in the css directory. Duh... It's fixed now and seems to be working properly. If someone can confirm that it's working properly and I have it setup right, that would be great. Because I have links setup for multiple "browser types" of the same font, do I have to list an alternate font? I would guess no but if someone knows for sure, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @urbanelementz Your 404 is gone, but the font still isn't displaying.  I'm checking your CSS.

Comment: Thomas, yes please check it. I just updated it so make sure it's the most recent version... Are you sure it's not showing? It seems to be working for me just fine. I have it pointing to "CartoGothicStd" right now and it seems to be working. Then if I change it to "CartoGothicStdBold" it goes bold, etc, etc??

Comment: What's the font supposed to look like? Does it look anything like Verdana?

Comment: Ohh ok cool. no problem. you scared me there for a second. It's nothing special but it's nice, clean and easy to read. That's all I want. Nothing special. I'll use the google api if I want anything out of the box. Thanks though for all your help.

Comment: Great, glad i could help! Remember to either mark this as answer or mark the question as answered so future users don't waste time writing replies. ;)

Comment: For sure. Thanks Thomas. By the way, what do you think of the site so far?

Comment: it looks fantastic! If i weren't a web dev myself, i'd be coming to you guys. :) very convincing.

Comment: lol. Thanks a lot my friend. It's always good to have some great feedback. Take care!